# Show last n comments

Tags: comments

let's say I have posts with hundreds of comments, and that I want to show only the last N comments and then a link to a page read them all. How would I display the last N comments?

Thank you,
Dino.

Comment: Where do you need this, on which page? Of the concrete post?

Answer (score 1):

See.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments

Set the orderby parameter to your desired value, possible values are.

```
comment_agent
comment_approved
comment_author
comment_author_email
comment_author_IP
comment_author_url
comment_content
comment_date
comment_date_gmt
comment_ID
comment_karma
comment_parent
comment_post_ID
comment_type
user_id
```

Refer to the link already provided for info on setting other parameters, and general examples.

Comment: Note that you need to replace the `comments_template()` with this, otherwise WP will still query the database for those hundreds of comments. To display all the comments on a separate page call the current page with a query argument like `?show_all_comments`. Get all the comments form the db if this argument is present, otherwise get only 10 or something like that

Comment: here's a similar thread which should help you do what you want: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5358/comment-filtering-search/5377#5377 (you'll need that sql query for all the comments part)

Comment: Why would you need a direct SQL query to fetch comments in this instance, this makes absolutely no sense to me at all. The user asked for a method for pulling comments, not specific to any kind of post or page, what relevance does the comment template have here? Curious for some clarification on your points.

Comment: ok I'll post the entire code in a new answer, it's easier to understand

Comment: Look forward to it... :)

Comment: Note that I assume he wants this on the single post page. If it's for a index page, then yes, `get_comments()` should be enough. Maybe we should wait for the OP clarification :) And if needed I'll post my idea

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use native functionality for comment pagination?

See [Enhanced Comment Display](http://codex.wordpress.org/Migrating_Plugins_and_Themes_to_2.7/Enhanced_Comment_Display), [Settings > Discussion](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Discussion_SubPanel) in Codex.